# 16.04 LTS install issues on dell optiplex 5040; not recognizing hard drive

Tags: grub2, dell

I have a Dell Optiplex 5040 that I would like 16.04 LTS ubuntu to run on. I was using this page [How to Install Ubuntu Linux on your Dell PC](http://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/19/SLN151664/en#BIOS) as a guide. My system uses M2 PCIe, so I followed this sub-page [Installing Ubuntu on Systems using PCIe M2 Card Drives on your Dell PC](http://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/19/SLN299303/en). I have disabled "Secure Boot" and have made sure UEFI is selected under my Dell Bootloader options.

I'm first doing "Try Ubuntu." and booting from my live USB that I configured using Lili usb creator.

After pressing English as my language, I am prompted to install Ubuntu. The option to "Download updates while installing Ubuntu" is not highlighted because I cannot get the Ubuntu to connect to a network, neither using wifi nor ethernet. I have selected Install third-party software. I next select "erase disk and install Ubuntu." Then, I get the message, "write the changes to disk?"

```
the partition tables of the following devices are changed: 
dev/nvme0n1
the following partitions are going to be reformatted:
partition #1 of /dev/nmve0n1 as ext4
partition #5 of /dev/nvme0n1 as swap
```

I select continue. During the install I get a message saying:

```
Executing 'grub-install/dev/nvme' failed
This is a fatal error.
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: I just found out a solution, from this site (http://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/19/SLN151841/en) that worked for me:

Instead of selecting "erase disk and install Ubuntu" I selected "Something else." 

Here I made a new partition table with the following scheme under /dev/nvme0n1: 
(1) (+) 500MB primary EFI beginning 
(2) (+) 20GB primary ext4 mounted as: /
(3) (+) 5GB primary ext4 use as: /home 
(4) (+) 40GB logical swap use as: /swap

Answer (score 0):

this is the best way to fix a failed grub install during installation:

1. restart. boot again from the USB and select "Try ubuntu without installing".
2. open a terminal with ctrl+alt+t
3. type these commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt update
sudo apt install boot-repair
sudo boot-repair
```

4. chose recommended repair.
5. after a while you will be asked to paste code in the terminal. you will need to open a new terminal window to do this. use ctrl+alt+t to do that.
6. after the interactive boot repair completes, restart, remove the installation media, and boot from your hard drive into your Ubuntu installation.